# how to Post multiple records to website from c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I would like to send multiple records to a website after reading the records from a database table. I can send a single record, but cannot loop through the records and send one at a time.

here is part of the code i am using:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

req.Method = "POST";

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 field1, field2, field3, field4 prices", conn);

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

WebResponse rs;
string strNewValue;

StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

while (rd.Read())

{


strNewValue = "field1='" + rd[0].ToString() + "'&field2='" + rd[1].ToString() + "'&field3='AM'&field4=" + rd[2].ToString();

stOut.Write(strNewValue);



}

stOut.Close();

rs = req.GetResponse();
```

this code only posts the last record. How can I loop through the records and post all of them one at a time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that the receiver doesn't read all of the rows correctly (it may be replacing each row read with the next row, so ending up with the last row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're putting all the records into the same http post - try changing it to post each record - something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 field1, field2, field3, field4 prices", conn);

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();


while (rd.Read())
{


HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

req.Method = "POST";

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


WebResponse rs; string strNewValue;

StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);


strNewValue = "field1='" + rd[0].ToString() + "'&field2='" + rd[1].ToString() + "'&field3='AM'&field4=" + rd[2].ToString();

stOut.Write(strNewValue);
stOut.Close();
rs = req.GetResponse();

}

rd.Close();
```

Comment: ps - just noticed, you should change rd[0].ToString() to HttpUtility.UrlEncode(rd[0].ToString()) in order to avoid errors when your database content includes characters such as = and &